# Getting the name / key of a JToken with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON that looks like this

```
[
  {
    "MobileSiteContent": {
      "Culture": "en_au",
      "Key": [
        "NameOfKey1"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "PageContent": {
      "Culture": "en_au",
      "Page": [
        "about-us/"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I parse this as a JArray:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Then, I loop over the array:

```
foreach (var content in array)
{

}
```

`content` is a `JToken`

How can I retrieve the "name" or "key" of each item?

For example, "MobileSiteContent" or "PageContent"

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`JToken` is the base class for `JObject`, `JArray`, `JProperty`, `JValue`, etc.  You can use the `Children<T>()` method to get a filtered list of a JToken's children that are of a certain type, for example `JObject`.  Each `JObject` has a collection of `JProperty` objects, which can be accessed via the `Properties()` method.  For each `JProperty`, you can get its `Name`.  (Of course you can also get the `Value` if desired, which is another `JToken`.)

Putting it all together we have:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject content in array.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MobileSiteContent
PageContent
```

Answer (score 33):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var attributes = obj["parent"]["child"]...["your desired element"]; 

foreach (JProperty attributeProperty in attributes)
{
    var attribute = attributes[attributeProperty.Name];
    var my_data = attribute["your desired element"];
}
```

Answer (score 29):

The default iterator for the JObject is as a dictionary iterating over key/value pairs.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);
foreach (var pair in obj) {
    Console.WriteLine (pair.Key);
}
```

Comment: Making the foreach clear: `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in obj)`

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq we can write something like:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject content in array.Children<JObject>())
{
    List<string> keys = content.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string name = jToken.Path.Split(".").Last();
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way is to look at the path of each item in the JSON object.

```
For Each token As JToken In json
        Dim key= token.Path.Split(".").Last
Next
```